# How to utilize UFW blocking published ports from docker

Tags: docker, ufw

Might seem a silly question but i'm trying to get the following to work:

- I have a correctly configured UFW for only allowing certain source IPs access to my local service
- after migrating this service into a docker container with a published port the port is publicly published

Thus every host can now access the published port from anywhere.

How can I restrict access via UFW to this published docker port?

The specific port this service is using is `3333`.

I've tried to get it to work using `-p 127.0.0.1:3333:3333` in order to bind the port to localhost. But then I'd need a proxy to go from the UFW-restricted public port to `localhost:3333`. I also tried to use `iptables -j REDIRECT`, but I couldn't get it to work.

So it's not a problem of the container restricting access to outside, it outside getting to the container.

I'd like to keep my current UFW setup with explicit whitelisting for Dockerized serviced.

Comment: I'm a little confused on what you're asking so let me sort of summarize what I think and you can tell me what I'm missing. You basically want to restrict access to a port exposed by Docker. Specifically you are trying to allow only certain hosts to communicate to port 3333 on your docker host, but your attempts to use Docker commands or iptables has not worked and every host in your network can still communicate to port 3333. Let me know if that is correct or not.

Comment: sounds about right... either through ```-P 3333:3333``` or ```-P 127.0.0.1:3333:3333``` both dont really work. I _can_ fix it by prepending my UFW rules manually after starting the container ```iptables -I FORWARD 1 -p tcp -i eth0 -s [allowedsourceIP] --dport 3333 -j ACCEPT``` but this breaks after restarting / stop+starting the container...

Comment: So UFW is not blocking the docker ports right?

Comment: It wasn't at time of writing the original question no...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found out a better more consistent solution in advance of the new docker iptables solution coming in 1.5+.

By not using the `FORWARD` chain but another the rules are handled *before* docker alters the iptable chains and thus will survive docker container restarts. If anyone ever needs it: this solved my issue of having custom iptable rules and docker on a host:

```
iptables -I PREROUTING 1 -t mangle ! -s [SOURCEIP_TO_ALLOW] -p tcp --dport [PORT] -j ACCEPT
iptables -I PREROUTING 2 -t mangle -p tcp --dport [PORT] -j DROP
```

The trick is the PREROUTING and mangle step. This way i can allow from SOURCEIP_TO_ALLOW on PORT on the host and disallow others coming in...!

Comment: Is the SOURCEIP_TO_ALLOW mandatory? Do I have to set it to the IP of my host? Or can I just skip the whole line?

Comment: Now I'm getting "iptables: Index of insertion too big."

Comment: the SOURCE IP TO ALLOW is indeed mandatory. So if your office IP is 1.2.3.4 and the port is 123 the result would end up:

iptables -I PREROUTING 1 -t mangle ! -s 1.2.3.4 -p tcp --dport 123 -j ACCEPT && iptables -I PREROUTING 2 -t mangle -p tcp --dport 123 -j DROP

Newest version of docker (1.5+) does handle the iptable stuff differently so this might be out of date btw...

Answer (score 0):

You have three options to publish/expose ports from docker:

- Neither specify EXPOSE nor -p means that the service in the container will be accessible only inside the container itself.
- Specify EXPOSE and -p the service in the container is accessible from anywhere.
- Specify EXPOSE only. The service is not accessible outside docker, but only between docker containers for inner container communication.

In case you have firewall in the host that blocks all incoming connections to port 3333, but you would like to have world wide access then you can use UFW to open the port or open the port for specified source hosts like this:

- ufw allow 3333 - this will open port 3333 for TCP and UDP connections from any source.
- ufw allow from 1.2.3.4 to any port 3333 - this will allow access only from source IP 1.2.3.4 to any IP in your host to port 3333.

Note that you can also specify protocol to be used with proto, otherwise ufw will open for both tcp and udp.

Comment: Actually when I read your question again I can add that -p includes EXPOSE, because if a port is open to the public, it is automatically open to other containers too. So to block outside access for evrybody just use second UFW rule that I suggest to specify which source IP to access your service only.

Comment: Thanks, but the problem persists. Due to the fact docker changes the iptables before ure can get to them..  thus publishing ports via -p will allow the world to connect irrelevant of what ufw tries to prevent later on..

Comment: Again, it's not about EXPOSE, its not about --link to other containers: it about having control over the publicly exposed port via UFW (as it were a normal service on the host)

Comment: As I see from above you have found the rule that fixes your issue, but you are saying that when Docker is restarted that broke. The reason is that Docker is reapplying the iptables rules. You should take care to better understand how iptables work and the UFW implementation in Ubuntu to deal with that. You can use iptables -nL or iptables-save to see how the firewall looks like before and after Docker start/stop and to take actions to make permanent rules.

Comment: So you're implying there is no real solution, just custom hacks for my docker run commands? (prepending it with iptable commands?) That surprises me greatly...really no _real_ solution

Comment: This whole situation with Docker and ufw/iptables is very frustrating!

Comment: For my use case (VersionEye Enterprise) the solution is to EXPOSE the ports in the Dockerfile but not to use the -p option at container start.